# Images too large under iOS 3.2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I noticed that when I test my app on the iPad 3.2 software, my buttons on the keypad do not look correct, they are enlarged.  When I test it on the 4.0 or above, everything looks great.  Any suggestions of what is going on?

[image]

I'll be more than happy to post code, just don't know which part to post?

Keep in mind the buttons are not enlarged like this in 4.0 or above.  Are there any programming difference between the two.

Also, all these buttons were created in interface builder.

Comment: Post the part of the code that creates the buttons, and tell us more about the images (size, resolution, name).

Comment: Are you sure that pink is the best choice for buttons and readout in a tip calculator?  The contrast on the segmented control isn't the best, and the black UIPickerView doesn't seem to fit with the rest of the interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using high resolution images for your buttons? Do the image names end in "...@2x"? The high-res image name convention was introduced with iOS 4 to support the retina display, and I doubt that iOS 3.2 makes any special provision for images named with th

Comment: There are only one set of images, and they are name in a manner such as button_one.png, and so on.

Comment: It sounds like your images are high res. Try scaling them down for devices that don't have the retina display as this answer suggests.

Comment: So you can have two sets of images in the app for each button, ect.  What's the naming scheme?

Comment: See [Specifying High-Resolution Images in iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/ImageSoundResources/ImageSoundResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH7-SW17).

Comment: Whoa, can't believe I didn't know that, thanks!  I thought this was just for icons.