# Regarding Resolution between iphone SDK 3.o and SDK 4.0

Tags: iphone

I have one application which is on iTunes now we build this app for iphone SDk 3.0 and above but when we running this app on iPhone SDK 4.0 then the resolution of images will decreases so it look very bad.

So can any one give me the solution for this how to overcome this problem.

Thanks.
Priyanka

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well ... the resolution of the images do NOT decrease ... Instead the resolution of the display is changed, and the image is displayed in the same size on a higher resolution display. That's why it looks so bad.

You need to save your images in 2 formats. Normal and high resolution.

Here you have a good article on what and how to do it: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/6/29/updating-for-the-iphone-4-retinal-display.html

Comment: Thanx for replay but according to that procedure it is not working, i was created two images like (I agree.png,I agree@2x.png) and place both in resource folder but it doesn't work. So can you tell me what is exact procedure for it.

Answer (score 1):

For iPhone4.0 and above has retina display, which has the double resolution of iPhone3.0. So for iPhone4 you need to use high resolution images. Please refer new iOS application programming tutorial.

Comment: Thanx for replay but according to that procedure it is not working, i was created two images like (I agree.png,I agree@2x.png) and place both in resource folder but it doesn't work. So can you tell me what is exact procedure for it.

Comment: If the device you are using has retina display(iPhone4), automatically I agree@2x.png is returned otherwise normal image I agree.png is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [SO thread from earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341481/images-too-large-under-ios-3-2/5341643#5341643) where someone had the opposite problem -- high resolution images displaying incorrectly on iOS 3.2. The solution is the same: provide images for both resolutions as explained in the document linked in the comments.

Comment: Thanx for replay but according to that procedure it is not working, i was created two images like (I agree.png,I agree@2x.png) and place both in resource folder but it doesn't work. So can you tell me what is exact procedure for it.

Comment: What are the Base SDK and Deployment Target settings for this project? Base SDK should be set to the latest SDK -- at this point, that'd be iOS SDK 4.3. Choosing the right image should be automatic if you used the @2x naming convention.